# MySQL UNION SELECT FOLLOWING NEXT COLUM ID

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a table to store rules for another selects and it has the following design:

| id | column | operator | value | next_rule_id | next_operator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mail | contains | @gmail.com | 2 | OR |
| 2 | mail | contains | @hotmail.com | 5 | AND |
| 3 | city | equals | NY | 5 | AND |
| 4 | mail | contains | jolie@ | 3 | AND |
| 5 | city | equals | NY | 4 | null |
| 6 | user_id | greater | 10 | null | null |

I need to select 1 rule id and return all rows based on next_rule_id

Here are some examples:

selecting rule id = 1 would return

```
1   mail    contains    @gmail.com  2   OR
2   mail    contains    @hotmail.com    5   AND
5   city    equals  NY  4   null
```

selecting rule id = 4 would return

```
4   mail    contains    jolie@  3   AND
3   city    equals  NY  5   AND
5   city    equals  NY  4   null
```

selecting rule id = 6 would return

```
6   user_id greater 10  null    null
```

**SOLUTION 1**

I've managed to do that with a temporary table and one loop. But I think there is better approaches to do that.

If anyone knows how to do that in a better way I would appreciate your help.

**SOLUTION 2**

I created this procedure that uses a loop too.

```
BEGIN
    SET @id = 1; -- hardcoded first id
    SET @rules = '';
    SET @next_id = NULL;

    loop1: LOOP
        SET @count = @count + 1;
        SELECT next_rule_id INTO @next_id FROM filter_rules WHERE id = @id;
        SET @rules = CONCAT(@rules, ',', @id);
        SET @id = @next_id;
        
        IF @id IS NULL THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP loop1;

    SELECT * FROM filter_rules WHERE FIND_IN_SET(filter_rules.id, @rules);
END
```

Comment: This just sounds like a bad idea

Comment: I know that. But I need to store custom filters and this was the only way I could imagine.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: version: 5.7.29

Comment: you should read up on http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/  or switch to mysql 8 or mariadb with recursive  cte

Comment: Why does 1 stop at 2?